# ConditionalAttribute and other special classes

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, attributes, language-features

The `ConditionalAttribute` can be used to remove calls to a marked method depending on the compiler symbols defined. I'm assuming we could not create this class ourselves since the compiler must be looking for it specifically.

I was wondering what other classes there are that the compiler, or language uses that we could not code ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The compiler looks for [`[ExtensionAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) to indicate extension methods (and classes containing extension methods).
- [`[DynamicAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute.aspx) is used to indicate that a member should be treated as type `dynamic` (even though the member type itself will just be `object`)
- [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) allows one assembly to access the internal members of another.

Basically look through the [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53w0dze.aspx) namespace, and examine the attributes in there... many of them will be handled specially by *a* compiler, even if it's not the C# compiler (e.g. [`DateTimeConstantAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.datetimeconstantattribute.aspx) isn't used by the C# compiler as far as I'm aware, but [`DecimalConstantAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.decimalconstantattribute.aspx) is. It's *possible* that the C# compiler will *consume* constant `DateTime` values even though it won't produce them...)

Answer (score 6):

in addition to those mentioned;

```
AttributeUsageAttribute
```

has special compiler support, since it restricts (at compile) how you can apply attributes

```
ObsoleteAttribute
```

is also used by the compiler to warn or error about usage.

I *suspect* though, that technically you *could* write all of these yourself - as long as you write your own core libarary and System.dll ;p The compiler is generally looking for a *pattern/signature*, since it must cater for different runtimes - and indeed you don't have to use the MS core libraries. The *behaviour*, however, is defined by the compiler, not the class - so you can't make it do anything different.

Comment: Good point, you could implement all of these special cases yourself if you were also willing to write your own C# compiler :)

Comment: @Matt - no, you don't need to write the compiler. You use the existing compiler but use `/nostdlib` to tell it not to use `mscorlib.dll`, and supply your own as defined in ECMA335 (including the published strong name signature etc)

Answer (score 0):

[SerializableAttribute] springs to mind. The compiler handles this differently to other attributes, I believe it's translated to a specific instruction in IL..

**EDIT** Looking at the IL for ArgumentException as an example, the class definition looks like this:

```
.class public auto ansi serializable beforefieldinit ArgumentException
```

Note the *'serializable' modifier. Usually with an attribute you would expect to see something like the following, but it is not there:

```
.custom instance void System.SerializableAttribute::.ctor() = (
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I was discounting that one since I thought we could code that one as it was only used by other classes.